# Full-disk encryption of existing system, 18.04 LTS

Tags: system-installation, encryption, vpn

As I understand it, if I want encryption on my existing system, 18.04 LTS, my best bet is full-disk encryption, and the best way to get that is to back up my data and re-install and encrypt during the process. If that's true, then I have some process-type questions.

What, precisely, do I back up? My Home directory, sure; anything else?

I have a VPN running and I hope I can get it again if I have to do so from start, but is there a way to back this up so I don't have to begin afresh?